# Can I bring the element to another sibling element when hovering? [CSS Animation]

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to get the element to move to another elements when the elements are hovered on.
Those elements are sibling since I want the one to overlay the another.

The following HTML and CSS give me not bad result.
But I don't want to use constant values for "width" and "left" to animate them.
Is there some way to place the moving element on the hovered elements without using constant position values?

```css
nav .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

nav .start-home,
a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  width: 105px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

nav .start-blog,
a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  width: 105px;
  left: 105px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

nav .start-projects,
a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  width: 135px;
  left: 210px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

nav .start-about,
a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  width: 115px;
  left: 345px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

nav .start-contact,
a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  width: 130px;
  left: 460px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
}


nav {
  margin: 27px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #34495e;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
nav a {
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 2px 30px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Projects</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <div class="animation start-home"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: if i understand you want to have a color overlay to move behind element ? and you also post full HTML/CSS code

Comment: https://soarcreator.github.io/
This is the website I am building. The menu you will see on that website is what I don't like in terms of CSS.

Comment: I included some rules from your offsite resource inside the question itself, hoping it's ok with you. If not, feel free to rollback the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the way to do it with only CSS, so I used JavaScript and modify style of elements.
It was kind of what I did not want to do.
If you know how to do it with only CSS, let me know.